# Vorbis Library in a project for Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, osx-mountain-lion, vorbis

I need to use the Vorbis Library in a project for Mac OS X. I've compiled the OGG and Vorbis libraries and added them as a framework in the project. The problem is that cannot load them when running the program, I get the error:

```
dlopen Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Versions/A/Ogg
....
Reason: image not found
```

If I add the two frameworks in /Library/Frameworks it works. I want the program not to depend on whether or not the user has installed the two libraries. How do I include them in the binary?

I tried to set *framework search paths* but it has no effect

I use XCode 3.2, libogg-1.3.3 and libvorbis-1.3.5

Comment: You could compile them as a static library and link against that.

Comment: Please give me details, how to do this successfully? I set the C++ standard library type as static but the result is the same.

Comment: To build OGG and vorbis as static libraries, create suitable Xcode projects.  Then include these libraries in the project for your app.

Comment: I did it, I made the mistake to add the framework not static files .a